# Doctrine 2 category_id always NULL when set ManyToOne relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm

When I insert new entry if I set ManyToOne relationship "Category" i will not able to fill "categoryId" field why ?

This is the Entity with the relationship :

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item extends Base
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     */
    private $category;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    public $categoryId;

}
```

This is a Base class I made for generate getter and setter and allow $entry->name = 'yo' instead of $entry->setName('yo');

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;

class Base
{
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (preg_match('#^get#i', $method)) {
            $property = str_replace('get', '', $method);
            $property = strtolower($property);
            return $this->$property;
        }

        if (preg_match('#^set#i', $method)) {
            $property = str_replace('set', '', $method);
            $property = strtolower($property);
            $this->$property = $args[0];
        }
    }

    public function fromArray(array $array = array()) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value; 
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i save new item :

```
$item = new \Application\Entity\Item();
$item->name = 'Computer';
$item->categoryId = '12';
$this->em->persist($item);
$this->em->flush();
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong! With Doctrine, you don't work with category_id column (and alike) but with relations. Doctrine will take care of columns.

You will have to read the docs but correct way would be:

```
$category = new Category() ;
$category->setName("Food") ;

$item = new Item() ;
$item->setName("Pizza") ;
$item->setCategory($category) ;

$em->persist($item) ;
$em->flush() ;
```

This is 100% correct way of doing things, you don't even need to persist newly create Category (Doctrine will do that for you). But manually trying to set category_id column is completely wrong way of doing things.

One more:
Don't try to make ActiveRecord of Doctrine2. When I was switching from D1 to D2, I was thinking of doing the same thing but at the end, figured it was waste of time. It looks like you are trying to make your own framework; do NOT do that. Learn Symfony2 instead; it is not easy but it is worth the time.

Comment: Thank you for your help my problem is solved. Can you tell me why you think ActiveRecord is waste if time, what DataMapper is better for ?

Comment: For a starter, you don't need to extend some BaseRecord class. Annotations are really cool and datamapper pattern forces you to think on objects, not columns. You can learn OOP easier if you start writting unit tests first, you will be suprised how clean your code will become. And if that is not good enough explanation, stick to argument from authority; best php guys around decided to go DM instead of AR.