# Symfony/Doctrine 2 ManyToOne relationship, ORM does not retain set value for column, error ensues

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I'm creating a ManyToOne relationship in table B, to one entry in table A.

I am using a particular key_id parameter, which is set in the controller, before being flushed to the db. My problem is that the SQL created by the ORM nulls the value for this key, for some reason. Before the ManyToOne relationship the same controller had no issues setting and persisting the key_id value.

Here is my annotation on Table B

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=63)
     * @Filter\Trim()
     * @Filter\StripNewlines()
     */
    private table_b_id

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TableA", inversedBy="table_b_entries", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="table_b_id", referencedColumnName="table_a_id")
     */
    private $reference_to_table_a;
```

And Table A

```
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->table_b_entries = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TableB", mappedBy="table_b_id")
     */
    private $table_b_entries;
```

The error that I get is:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'table_b_id' cannot be null`

Although I DO set it in the controller before flushing to db, and I have verified the object that I flush that it contains the value, however the SQL does NOT contain this value anymore... I'm not sure where or why it gets lost...

#### Update

The error described here is because I was not setting the reference object, but trying to set the reference column id manually on Table B. I Should have first fetched the Table A, and set that object on Table B, through the reference setter...

The initial question was answered by: [Doctrine 2 category_id always NULL when set ManyToOne relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398469/doctrine-2-category-id-always-null-when-set-manytoone-relationship)

Now I'm dealing with another error:

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: table_a_id in
>   /vagrant/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 628

Comment: Please paste controller code where you are setting the value.

Comment: You're probably alluding to the right thing, I was manually setting the foreign key id, instead of setting the relation through by setting the foreign object...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two fields for ManyToOne relation. This is sufficient:

```
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="entitiesB")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="name_of_column_on_table_b", referencedColumnName="column_from_table_a_to_be_referenced")
     */
    private $entityA;

    // ...
}

class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="entityA")
     */
    private $entitiesB;

    // ...
}
```

Doctrine will automatically create field called `entityA_id` on your `B` table, index it and create foreign key between the two.

When you have instance of entity `B`, you can retrieve it's `A` record relation Id by just calling:

```
$b->getEntityA()->getId()
```

People commonly think that this will trigger another query, but it will not, it will just read `entityA_id` from `B` record, for exaplanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine/19146723#19146723)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to set a specific key column, so I can't just use the default ones generated by doctrince. Which is why I set `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="table_b_id", referencedColumnName="table_a_id")`

Comment: it just seems something may be off about `referencedColumnName`?

Comment: Then just include JoinColumn on your relation field, there is still no need to have an extra ID field

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand, I have to use the common "extra" ID field, because that's how the tables are set-up. And I'm using JoinColumn to specify the two columns that should be joined: on Table A, `table_a_id`, and on Table B `table_b_id`, these are different from each tables own `id` column, and Table B, does not reference the `id` column of Table A, but another column in Table A, `table_a_id` in this example...

Comment: It doesn't have to be id field, that's just default if nothing is set, you can place any column you want as I've updated in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing, I've gotten over the initial error from this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398469/doctrine-2-category-id-always-null-when-set-manytoone-relationship however I'm dealing with a new problem now, as I've updated my question :)

Comment: Check your inversedBy and mappedBy column names on relation annotations.

Comment: Do I need to make table_a_id a primary index?

Comment: Then I'm confused about what `ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: table_a_id in /vagrant/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 628` means... :)